# A function to tabulate output from several classification algorithms on different data-sets

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that produces the output from several classification algorithms on different data-sets in a summary table. I am using the `caret` package.

I will attempt to walk-through the different bits of code that I have thus far:

```
library(foreign)  ## Get a concacated list of files is working directry
f<-c(dir())

##  create and view an object with file names and full paths
file<-file.path("C:/Users/Documents/Datasets",c (f))

# use a loop to read all of these files from my working directry
dlist<-lapply(file,read.table,header=TRUE,sep="\t")
lapply(d, names)
```

So `dlist` contains my set of training and test data-sets. I have already split my data; so for example, the files are named `pca.test`, `pca.train`, `svm.test`, `svm.train`, `rf.train`, `rf.test`. Just realized that the files in `dlist` are also already data.frames in R, i.e. I created them first in R, then saved them as tab-delimited files (REDUNDANT!).

For each pair of data-sets (pca.test and pca.train for example), I would like to perform different classification  and prediction methods:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(100)

# Classification method 1, Naive baiyes
model_pca.NB = train(pca.train[,-5],pca.train[,5],'nb',   trControl=trainControl(method='cv',number=5))

pca.nb.pred<-predict(model_pca.NB, pca.test[,-5])
nb.conf<-confusionMatrix(pca.nb.pred,pca.test[,5])

# Classification method 2, LDA
set.seed(100)
ctrl <- trainControl( repeats = 5, method='cv', number = 5,
                  allowParallel = FALSE)

model.pca.LDA <- train(Species~., data= pca.train,
             method = "lda", trControl = ctrl)

pred.anova.LDA<-predict(model.pca.LDA, pca.test[,-5])
lda.conf<-confusionMatrix(pred.anova.LDA,pca.test[,5])

# Classification method 3, ANN
set.seed(100)
mlpcontrol<-trainControl(method='cv',
                       number =2, repeats=2, returnResamp = 'none')

model.pca.ann<-train(Species~., data=pca.train, method='mlp',
  tuneGrid = data.frame(.size = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)),
  allowParallel = TRUE, trControl=mlpcontrol)

pred.pca.ann<-predict(model.pca.ann, pca.test[,-5])
ann.conf<-confusionMatrix(pred.pca.ann,pca.test[,5])
```

For a reproducible example, will be using the `iris` data-set; both for the training and test:

```
pca.train<-iris;  pca.test<-iris
```

By using lda.conf$byClass, I can access a table listing

```
> lda.conf$byClass
 Sensitivity Specificity Pos Pred Value Neg Pred Value Prevalence       Detection Rate   Detection Prevalence
Class: setosa            1.00        1.00      1.0000000       1.000000  0.3333333        0.3333333            0.3333333
Class: versicolor        0.96        0.99      0.9795918       0.980198  0.3333333      0.3200000            0.3266667
Class: virginica         0.98        0.98      0.9607843       0.989899  0.3333333      0.3266667            0.3400000
```

From each pair of data-sets and for each method, I would like to obtain the `Sensitivity`, `Specificity` and `Pos Pred` in one table... I would suppose `cbind`, but I am not sure how to get the labeling to reflect the classification method and the data-set used. So something to the effect of:

```
pca_LDA_Sensitivity  pca_lda_Specifi   pca_lda_PosPred pca_ANN_Sensistivity svm_LDA_Sensitivity.....
      1                        1              1                      .98
```

Then I would need the same for (more than likely a separate table) the accuracy and Kappa values accessed via `lda.conf$overall`.

Just for safety, I may need the individual confusion matrices (`lda.conf$table`) per pair of data-set for each method.

Lastly, I would like to create a list of all the results from the `train` functions.

I am not sure how to proceed with implementing a function to do the above. I am aware that the question is long, but I would appreciate any assistance given.

Answer (score 1):

I have been tackling a similar problem, what i did was write the results to several files using sink, and graphs to pdf files in varying levels of detail. I set up a folder structure with the key things for me in the first folder (confusion matrices and roc curves), then more detail in sub folders. So in my setup i train my models first with caret, then have a section of code that runs through model one by one and picks out the details. I just typed this code manually because i didn't think it worth the effort of trying to automate it.

Comment: Thanks Kharoof, Guess I will have to go the old fashioned way.